# How to package Gulp tasks inside an npm package?

Tags: npm, gulp

I have developed a set of Gulp tasks that I would like to use in other projects. Is it possible to publish Gulp tasks in an npm package?

Then do `npm install -g myGulpTasks` and call one of my task's like `gulp mytask` to run globally on my project directory. If so, how is this done? I can't find any docs on this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
It is possible.

Need to create something like this module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/liferay-theme-tasks

It has registered tasks which can run on any liferay-theme project.